# Allow different users to login with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a database table with `users` and a specific field named `status` which will have three values:

`0` - For user that is registered but has no access till admin changes his status to 1.

`1` - For a `normal` user that is registered and approved.

`2` - Is the status for an `admin` user.

So now i want to let those who have status 1 (`normal` users) and 2(`admin` user) to login, but apparently i can't do it with this method i add to LoginController.

I have to pass only `['status' => 1]` or `['status' => 2]` but not both and that will prevent either users or admins from logging.

Can anyone help me?

```
 protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'),
        (['status' => 1]) || (['status' => 2]));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look into extending the functionality found in Auth

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that will solve your problem of logging in and also protect your routes from direct visits from non-authorized users. If all you want is just to block the actual login, see the other answer by @thefallen. But if you want a little further protection beyond just the login form, you could wrap ALL of your protected routes in a middleware that checks to see if the user's "status" is equal to 1 or 2. If it's not, you can log them out. This doesn't actually block them from logging in on the front end, but does guarantee that a user that is not approved can not access protected routes and will be logged out immediately when they do. Assuming that you redirect your users to a protected route when they login, the middleware would effectively log them out right there on that first request. The middleware could look like this:

```
class AuthorizedUser
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && !in_array(Auth::user()->status, [1, 2])) {
            Auth::logout();
            abort(404);
        } else if(Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the $middelwareGroups array to wrap your protected routes in this middleware, something like this in the Http\Kernel.php file:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'authorized' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AuthorizedUser::class,
    ]
];
```

You can change the 404 functionality to whatever you want, such as redirecting back to a login page or the home page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to overwrite the **authenticated()** method in the LoginController which is executed when the user successfully logs in:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (in_array($user->status, [1, 2])) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    auth()->logout();

    return redirect('/login')->withErrors(['email' => 'You can not login.']);
}
```

This way you can check if the user has the correct status and if it does't you can log out and redirect with error message. Don't forget to import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top.

If you need another solution where you actually check the status of the user before attempting the login, its a lot of changes in the default methods.

Comment: Thanks! Where can l learn all these. I find laravel a bit wide and not so simple when you dive a bit deeper?